# CreateCache.exe stuck in NCache caching software (open source edition)

Tags: caching, distributed-caching, ncache

Every time I am trying to create new cache through `createcache.exe` (using commands like `createcache.exe ClusteredCache` or `createcache.exe ClusteredCache /s <ip> /t local`), program starts and does not output any result (about success or failure of this operation), and the process cannot be stopped in any way. When in different window I will input `listcaches.exe`, new cache doesn't show up, so I guess it was not created.

Comment: Did you install `NCache` with `admin` install rights ? The same commands works for me though

Comment: Yes, I have installed it with admin rights. When I tried without I had errors during install...

Comment: When you run `listcache.exe` you see three caches right? `mycache` , `myReplicatedCache` and `myPartitionedCache`. This means at least your service is up and running.

Comment: Yes I can list these three caches. That is why this problem is bothering me so much. Everything except createcache appears to be up and running. I also have not see any error, and I have one other server with set up NCache cache, and everything there work flawlessly.

Comment: Can you run these two commands in series ? `addclientnode.exe myreplicatedcache /s <LOCALIP> /e <LOCALIP>` then followed by `removeclientnode.exe myreplicatedcache /e <LOCALIP> /s <LOCALIP>`

Comment: addcliendnode.exe command gets stuck without an error too.

Comment: Basically whatever user you are running the tools from may not have the right access right to edit the config files. That's a guess. Those commands that you just ran edit those files. Can you check your rights ? NCache installation folder

Comment: Ok so indeed some users didn't have all rights. In order to check if this is the case I gave following users full access, and it still doesn't work: ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES; CREATOT OWNER; SYSTEM; Administrators; Users; TrustedInstaller; Is there any other user I should give permissions for?

Comment: Since the issue is with your rights. Can you first try by restarting your NCache service ? If that fails then go to `C:\Program Files\NCache\bin\resources` and edit `privileges.bat` & add `setacl.exe -on "%1config"  -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:Users;p:write" -rec cont` underneath `REM LOG_FILES Permisison Settings` (The file is read-only) then run `SetACLVISTA.exe`. If doen right, restart NCache service and check `createcache.exe `

Comment: The above command will give your current user edit rights to NCache service, Hope it works.

Comment: I have added this line of code of yours underneath what was already in priviliges.bat, underneath the line REM LOG_FILES Permission Settings, and I tried to run SetACLVISTA.exe, but it gives an error: "The system cannot fin the file specified". I tried to run priviligies.bat instead, and it starts but it gives errors like: The system cannot find the file specified or The SID for a trustee could not be found

Comment: Did you run it as admin ?

Comment: Yes, I ran it as admin.

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\NCache\config` folder exist ?

Comment: Yes, and it contains two files: client.ncconf and config.ncconf

Comment: I guess you have also tried restarting the NCache service. Yes now I do agree with you that your situation is pretty frustrating. Let me check what else did we miss

Comment: Yes I tried restart many times. I don't know if it helps but here are the lines that after run of privilige.bat shows the errors: setacl.exe -on "log-files"  -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:ASPNET;p:write;s:n;i:np;m:grant;w:dacl" -rec cont <= The SID for a trustee could not be found; setacl.exe -on "config" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:Users;p:write" -rec cont <=The system cannot find the file specified; setacl.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog"  -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:ASPNET;p:full;s:n;i:np;m:grant;w:dacl" -rec yes <= The SID for a trustee could not be found

Comment: it helps. Let me check

Comment: Can you replace `%1` with the location to your installation folder ending with a `\`. Also change `ASP' with `Users` like in the command i gave you. Then simply run the `privileges.bat`

Comment: Ok so I have changed this linnes containing %1 ASPNet, so they look like this: setacl.exe -on "C:\Program Files\NCache\log-files"  -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:Users;p:write;s:n;i:np;m:grant;w:dacl" -rec cont; setacl.exe -on "C:\Program Files\NCache\config" -ot file -actn ace -ace "n:Users;p:write" -rec cont; setacl.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog"  -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:Users;p:full;s:n;i:np;m:grant;w:dacl" -rec yes; The process finished succesfully but still I have received errors like: Writing SD to <machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog

Comment: \Windows\PowerShell\PowerShell> failed with: Access is denied. Edit: CreateCache still doesn't work

Comment: `Access is denied` Should not happen

Comment: I double checked it and I am sure I am using administrator rights to open it.

Comment: Well, I don't have anything else that I can say. Tried re-installing NCache ? What I think is that your Windows have some security issues given the fact that NCache works in your other servers just fine.

Comment: I have resintalled it couple of times already. Ok, thanks then for you help.

Comment: Yeah sure. Happy to help

Comment: You could try to post the same question at http://www.alachisoft.com/forum

Comment: Yes, I guess I have no other choice